# Add Sequence to Rows in SELECT Statement

Tags: t-sql, datetime, select, sequence, row-number

I'm required to extract transactions from a table which may have transaction for customer happening on the same day.  For these transaction I must add a sequence column only for the same day transactions.

```
 CustAcct      Transdate     TransAmt 
 00001         2/1/2000        100
 00001         2/1/2000        150
 00005         3/2/2000        250
 00001         2/1/2000        100
```

We want data to be shown as:

```
 CustAcct      Transdate     TransAmt   Seq
 00001         2/1/2000        100       1
 00001         2/1/2000        150       2
 00005         3/2/2000        250       NULL
 00001         2/1/2000        100       3
```

I thought of using the ROW_NUMBER() function but not sure how only use it for rows with same date and acct numbers.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you wanting to add an identity to could the numer of rows or add a number to duplicated rows? Do the column need to be permanent or just when you query the table?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you're looking for:

```
SELECT 
    CustAcct
    ,TransDate
    ,TransAmt
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TransDate,CustAcct ORDER BY CustAcct)
FROM Cust
```